# How do I animate emission with an audio file?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, audio

In cycles,

I want an audio file of speech to cause an emission surface to change the amount of emission strength to match the volume from the voice actor's audio file. 
No sound = 0 strength
Loudest sound = 10 strength

How do I connect one event to control the other?
Also, can a specific audio file can be isolated to ignore other dialog and sound effects?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

For convenience later on, I'll add a Value node, which you can connect to the emission strength or any other input.

1. Set a key on the property, which you want to be "animated" by the sound wave.
   [image]
2. In the graph editor, execute *Bake Sound to F-Curves*.
   [image]
3. Adjust the resulting F-Curve with an **Envelope** modifier, mapping the output from 1 to 10. Or map the input from 0 to 1 and add a multiply node in the cycles material nodes to multiply it with 10.
   [image]

Comment: Why does it say "Set a key" what does that mean? The image shows connected nodes, doesn't seem to correlate.

Comment: @EricHuelin I added a few words to clarify. In my example, I added the **Value** node. Then I hovered over the Value Node's Value and pressed **I** to set a key. You can see the field being highlighted in yellow. This means it has been keyed and there will be a corresponding f-curve. I suggested setting keys and animating on a separate node, because it can be connected to whatever. Let's say you did all the animating in the **Strength** property of the Emission, but later on wanted to transfer the animation to a color ramp (as in my example), you wuold be stuck.